# WebJobs TFS build for debug and release

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-webjobs

I've segragated app.config of webjobs project with slowcheetah to debug and release configs.

I've put **webjobs-list.json** into webapp project with content:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../LocationApp.WebJobs/LocationApp.WebJobs.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am stuck here now, since there are two connection strings which we have to add into azure portal settings:

- AzureWebJobsDashboard
- AzureWebJobsStorage

If Azure cannot read into app.config how can we publish these correspondingly for debug or release websites?
How do we setup TFS build for webjobs, so it takes debug or release version when needed for webjobs.

Comment: How do you publish your job for the moment ? when you publish any .net app you specify the configuration you want like debug release or any other custom configuration.

Comment: I use publish as webjob which creates publish profile in webjobs Properties folder. I would like to automate this with tfs build.

Comment: May be this article could be interesting for you https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/